# How to show error message for a Stripe card error in Flask

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to show an HTML page with the reason for error with Flask and Stripe.
Here is the functional code, it does show the error, but also includes the request number etc

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    app.logger.error('Server Error: %s', (error))
    return render_template('500.html', error=error), 500

@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.CardError)
def stripe_card_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.CardError: %s', (e))

    #record_payment_error('stripe-card-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200



@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.RateLimitError)
def stripe_ratelimit_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.RateLimitError: %s', (e))
    #record_payment_error('stripe-rate-limit-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200


@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.InvalidRequestError)
def stripe_invalid_request_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: %s', (e))
    #record_payment_error('stripe-invalid-request-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200


@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.AuthenticationError)
def stripe_authentication_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.AuthenticationError: %s', (e))
    #record_payment_error('stripe-authentication-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200


@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.APIConnectionError)
def stripe_api_connection_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.APIConnectionError: %s', (e))
    #record_payment_error('stripe-api-connection-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200


@app.errorhandler(stripe.error.StripeError)
def stripe_generic_error(e):
    app.logger.error('Stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: %s', (e))
    #record_payment_error('general-stripe-error')
    return render_template('500.html', e=e), 200
```

Here is the printout: ERROR in stripeApp_test: Stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: R
equest req_IYV89ouQOL6oat: You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1EE0NzFMs
ALZZse8mUxZzY6i.

I would like to just print "You cannot use a Stripe token more than once"

I am sorry if this is a bad question, I am very new!

Comment: Does the error object has some other information like error code? If yes you could use it.

Comment: You shouldn't show a `stripe.error.InvalidRequestError` to your users at all, because it's an integration error and not an error for the customer themselves to fix, it's something you should just log instead so you as the developer can fix it, and tell the user "Sorry, there was a problem processing your payment!"

Comment: the problem with using "Sorry, there was a problem processing your payment!"  is that if a user typed in a wrong zip code, or card number the customer themselves can fix it. The generic error code was how I was originally handling it, but ran into a couple issues.